# Is it possible to image android phone and run on emulator?

Tags: emulators

I have an LG phone with faulty screen that I am not interested in fixing, but I am interested in an installed app.
I am looking for a way to convert it to an image and run it on my PC, is that possible?
Searching online just shows me results for how to transfer images from my phone to my PC :D

Answer (score 0):

Hope you're doing well.

You said you're interested in an application, well let me try and clear it up, but if you just want to use an application, you're better off with running it fresh on an emulator, and that way you will not have to worry about your broken phone, but if it is the app data you're interested in then I'd suggest you'd take a backup of your phone, that will basically be an image of your broken phone, using adb tools and then restore it onto an emulator. But you will have to look it up as to how you want to flash adb tools onto your phone without a display(assuming your display is completely dead).

Otherwise, your topic seems a little too broad